# FreeRDP takes too long to fail

Tags: freerdp

I am configuring a jump box which (amongst other clients) will connect to targets using xfreerdp.

Going down the happy path (target RDP server is switched on, correct credentials supplied) it works really well. However if the user supplies an incorrect password, xfreerdp takes over 2 minutes to fail!

The options I am currently using are....

```
 xfreerdp /v:$MYHOST /u:$RDPUSER /p:$MYPASS \
        /size:$DIMENSIONS /sec-rdp /cert-ignore \
        /kbd:0x00000452 /p
```

Looking at the man page I see no way to limit the length of time it tries to connect. While I could script a monitor for the task which kills it after (say) 20 seconds - but it won't know if the session is running successfully, or is stuck in the chain of events which will lead to "protocol security negotiation or connection failure" (error 131).

Short of testing the credentials using a different route (smbclient?) is there any way to make this more responsive?

Do other RDP clients behave better in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

While in earlier iterations I was only able to get a successful connection using "/sec-rdp", in the current version of xfreerdp/my script/target system, "/sec-tls" works and fails in approx 1 second.